# Android Suppress UnusedAttribute Warning For Specific Attributes

Tags: android, android-lint

I have a few linter warnings for "UnusedAttribute" throughout my project.

- Attribute `elevation` is only used in API level 21 and higher (current min is 16)
- Attribute `breakStrategy` is only used in API level 23 and higher (current min is 16)
- Attribute `hyphenationFrequency` is only used in API level 23 and higher (current min is 16)
- Attribute `letterSpacing` is only used in API level 21 and higher (current min is 16)

---

I know that I can suppress the warning for ALL of the attributes.

```
tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
```

or

```
lintOptions {
    disable 'UnusedAttribute'
}
```

---

However, I only want to suppress the warning for specific attributes. I tried to do the following without success.

```
tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute:elevation"
```

or

```
lintOptions {
    disable 'UnusedAttribute:elevation'
}
```

---

I can't find any mention of this in the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html), [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint), [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks), or [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For that you have configure lint via `lint.xml` and use regexp [see docs for details](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html#pref). Let's go step by step.

Firstly, specify that you will use file configuration.
Something like that in your `build.gradle`

```
lintOptions {
    lintConfig file("../config/lint/lint.xml")
}
```

In your case path will be different.

Secondly, use regexp to exclude specific attributes. Here is example of `lint.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="UnusedAttribute">
        <ignore regexp="elevation"/>
        <ignore regexp="breakStrategy"/>
    </issue>
</lint>
```

Another way to do it is to add `tools:targetApi="n"` for each usage. Where "n" is version where attribute first appeared.